# Spring container doesn't inject dependencies after the introduction of the aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

The project worked well before using AOP, but after adding the `LoggingAspect` class, a `NullPointerException` appeared. I did the project debugging and at the point where the `NullPointerException` appears, there is no object that has a method to call. The `defaultLogger` object is embedded in the constructor of the `Runner` object. Why it happens? [Link to the project](https://github.com/LordDetson/Spring-AOP)

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(* *.logEvent(..))")
    public void allLogEventMethods() {}

    @Before("allLogEventMethods()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("BEFORE: " +
                joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName() + " " +
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="allLogEventMethods()",
            returning="retVal")
    public void logAfter(Object retVal) {
        System.out.println("AFTER_RET: " + retVal);
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="allLogEventMethods()",
            throwing="ex")
    public void logAfterThrow(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("AFTER_THR: " + ex);
    }
}

@Component
public class Runner {
    private Client client;
    private EventLogger defaultLogger;
    private Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggers;

    @Autowired
    public Runner(
            Client client,
            EventLogger defaultLogger,
            Map<EventType, EventLogger> loggerMap) {
        this.client = client;
        this.defaultLogger = defaultLogger;
        this.loggers = loggerMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ac = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        Runner app = ac.getBean(Runner.class);
        Event event;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            event = ac.getBean(Event.class);
            event.setMessage("Some event for " + i++);
            app.logEvent(null, event);
        }
        while (i < 20) {
            event = ac.getBean(Event.class);
            event.setMessage("Some event for " + i++);
            app.logEvent(EventType.INFO, event);
        }
        while (i < 30) {
            event = ac.getBean(Event.class);
            event.setMessage("Some event for " + i++);
            app.logEvent(EventType.ERROR, event);
        }

        ac.close();
    }

    private void logEvent(EventType type, Event message) {
        EventLogger eventLogger;
        if (type == null) eventLogger = defaultLogger;
        else eventLogger = loggers.get(type);
        eventLogger.logEvent(message);                //NullPointerException
    }
}
```

The relevant object is annotated with `@Component ("defaultLogger")`.

```
@Component("defaultLogger")
public class CacheFileLogger extends FileLogger {
    private int cacheSize;
    private List<Event> events;

    public CacheFileLogger(
            @Value("${filename}") String filename,
            @Value("${cacheSize}") int cacheSize
    ) {
        super(filename);
        this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
        events = new ArrayList<>(cacheSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void logEvent(Event event) {
        events.add(event);
        if (cacheSize == events.size()) {
            writeAndClearCache();
        }
    }

    private void writeAndClearCache() {
        for (Event event1 : events) {
            super.logEvent(event1);
        }
        events.clear();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        if (!events.isEmpty()) {
            writeAndClearCache();
        }
    }
}
```

File context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="by.babanin"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
</beans>
```

[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcCD7.png)

Comment: Spring AOP is implemented using proxies. A proxy is created and method calls will pass on to the actual object instead of the proxy. However this only works for public methods. As you are calling a `private` method it is called on the proxy which has `null` fields. Make your method `public` so it will pass-on to the wrapped instance.

Comment: Thanks you! It helped me. Where can I read about it? I do not quite understand why privet methods are called by a proxy object, and not by an actual object. There is an assumption that it does not implement the interface with the logEvent method, since proxy objects work with interfaces. If you know the chapter in the Spring documentation, please tell me.

Comment: Proxies can be for classes as well. A proxy can only see public and protected methods. Everything else it simply cannot access and as such proxy based app (be it class or interface) is limited to public/protected methods. Basically proxy  based app can only access methods you could override in a subclass. If you would create a subclass of `Runner` you wouldn't be able to access the private method. You would be able to access and override public/protected methods. The same access rules apply to proxies.

Comment: Thanks you! I understood that. Please duplicate your comment in my reply, which I can call an answer only after 2 days((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error corrected, thanks to the comments on this issue.
I changed the private method `logEvent`class Runner, to public! I would explain why this worked, but I don’t quite understand why. If I know, I will leave an explanation in the comments to this answer.

```
public void logEvent(EventType type, Event message) {
        EventLogger eventLogger;
        if (type == null) eventLogger = defaultLogger;
        else eventLogger = loggers.get(type);
        eventLogger.logEvent(message);
    }
```

Comment: Proxies can be for classes as well. A proxy can only see public and protected methods. Everything else it simply cannot access and as such proxy based app (be it class or interface) is limited to public/protected methods. Basically proxy based app can only access methods you could override in a subclass. If you would create a subclass of Runner you wouldn't be able to access the private method. You would be able to access and override public/protected methods. The same access rules apply to proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Your eventLogger object becomes null in when you call logEvent method. Make sure to pass objects without null references to constructor of the runner class through your context.xml.What I've written here is only for passing eventLogger object to the constructor of Runner class. You have to do the same for other two parameters of the constructor as well. Make sure share your results with us.

```
<bean id="Runner" class="com.xyz.abc.Runner">
    <property name="EventLogger ">
      <bean class="com.xyz.abc.EventLogger ">
        <property name="param1" value="value1" />
        <property name="param2" value="value2" />
        <property name="param3" value="value3" />
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I use annotations. The Spring log says that the objects are entered into the constructor of the Runner class: 15: 09: 04.749 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - “runner”
15: 09: 04.750 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - “runner” via constructor to bean named 'defaultLogger'
15: 09: 04.750 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - “runner” via constructor to bean named 'loggerMap'

Comment: Question: Why does the eventLogger object become zero when I call the logEvent method?